# Key Bindings 1-5 not working Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, key-bindings

I'm using Python's Tkinter for a little project, and I need to use the number pad for key binding. However, the keys 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 are not responding. All other keys work just fine. 
For example:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.title('Key Test')
c = Canvas(window, height=500, width=500)
c.pack()
word = c.create_text(250, 250, text='Spam')
def transformation(event):
    c.itemconfig(word, text='Spamalot')
c.bind_all('<6>', transformation)
```

The above code works perfectly fine. But putting '5' in the binding rather than '6' makes the program unresponsive. I have tried doing this in other windows, and I have even tried using a different keyboard.
Nothing seems to work. Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: `<1>` is treated as an abbreviated version of `<Button-1>`, not `<Key-1>`.  5 mouse buttons are supported, thus the limit of the issue you're seeing.

Comment: @jasonharper Tested successfully 1 through 3 but 4 and 5 don't seam to work. Would you happen to know what 4 and 5 map to? I thought it was scroll up and scroll down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have no idea why `<6>` works, but the key events are officially called `<Key-…>`, see the [keysyms manual page](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/keysyms.htm):

```
c.bind_all('<Key-5>', transformation)
```

**EDIT** Based on [Jason Harper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1709364/jasonharper)'s and [Mike - SMT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7475225/mike-smt)'s suggestion, I looked at the Tk source code (in `generic/tkBind.c`), and it indeed does this:

```
    if ((*field >= '1') && (*field <= '5') && (field[1] == '\0')) {
        if (eventFlags == 0) {
            patPtr->eventType = ButtonPress;
            eventMask = ButtonPressMask;
        } else if (eventFlags & KEY) {
            goto getKeysym;
        } else if (!(eventFlags & BUTTON)) {
…
        }
        patPtr->detail.button = (*field - '0');
    } else {

    getKeysym:
        patPtr->detail.keySym = TkStringToKeysym(field);
```

So `<1>` to `<5>` are indeed special-cased as pointer device/mouse buttons.  Sneaky.

Comment: Thanks for adding that in. I was not 100% sure if that was what was going on. Good to know where the the code is to verify my guess.

Comment: After some digging I found this reference that explains how 1,2 and 3 work and how 4 and 5 work under linux. [Tkinter 8.5 reference: a GUI for Python](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/event-handlers.html). `If the event was related to a mouse button, this attribute is set to the button number (1, 2, or 3). For mouse wheel support under Linux, bind Button-4 and Button-5 events; when the mouse wheel is scrolled up, this field will be 4, or 5 when scrolled down.` So 4 and 5 might not work for windows users.

Comment: @Edmond301 Please make sure to select the check mark next to the answer that solved your issue.